# Rewrite URL add parameter with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I add parameter to this url:

> http://example.com/?p=10455

for ex:

> http://example.com/100/?p=10455

and it will redirect to the same location, only with additional parameter (num=100)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=10455(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /100/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.php?num=$1 [L,QSA]
```